# AWS elasticbeanstalk 100 % of cpu is in use degrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am runing my Springboot app on elastic beanstalk with classic load balancer (2 instance) on my test account t2.micro.

After deploy my app it degrade because of health and showing  "100 of cpu is in use " .

I have restarted server and EC2 instance but no luck .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found issue : update here to help others.

Steps to debug :

1) Download all logs

2) go  to AWS\BundleLogs-xxxxx\var\log folder

3) Open web-1.log

In my case issue is - [Spring Boot - can't start with embedded tomcat error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701983/spring-boot-cant-start-with-embedded-tomcat-error)

So server keep try to restart and eat up  100 CPU and app gets degrade.